# String into JSON Format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

Need one help.

I have two strings in two different variables;

`var var1 = "Myname";`

`var var2 = "Myage";`

`var jsonObj = ?`

`console.log(jsonObj);`

I would like to have the console output of "jsonObj" into a JSON object(not a key value pair) created from these strings in the below format;

`{"Myname":"Myage"}`

Please let me know how can achieve this?

Comment: ``{[var1]:var2}``

Comment: @MajedBadawi - thanks for the reply. I have elaborated my question with more details just now. Can you please have a look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
const var1 = "Myname", var2 = "Myage";

const jsonObj = { [var1]: var2 };

const res = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

console.log(res);
```